# Picking a default sound card

Tags: sound, lubuntu, alsa, hdmi, chromebook

I'm running Lubuntu on a Chromebook (Acer C720) and having issues with getting any sound.

`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` seems to be the default configuration from Ubuntu and as I understand it, modules with index 0 will be used by default.

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

If I look at the current cards in `/proc/asound/cards` I can see two available cards.

```
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                     HDA Intel HDMI at 0xe0510000 irq 44
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xe0514000 irq 45
```

The HDMI sound card has the default index, which is why the audio jack and speakers aren't working.

A look at the modules they use, `/proc/asound/modules`

```
0 snd_hda_intel
1 snd_hda_intel
```

Shows that they both use the same module. If both cards have that same module, how can I use the `alsa-base.conf` to specify that I want to use the PCH card by default?

Answer (score 1):

[alsa.opensrc.org](http://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleCards#Ordering_multiple_cards_of_the_same_type) has a short section which describes a scenario similar to this problem.

> If you have more that one sound cards which use the same modules, you may want to define the card order. This can be done by specifying index and ID options to the module being loaded. For example,
>
> options snd-usb-audio index=1,2 vid=0x0ccd,0x0d8c pid=0x0028,0x000c
>
> This will define 2 usb sound cards, the first one at index=1, vid=0x0ccd and pid=0x0028; the second one at index=2, vid=0x0d8c and pid=0x000c. The vid and pid here were discovered using lsusb.

Neither soundcard is a USB device, so you can't get hold of the module fields with `lsusb`, however that same article suggests using `modinfo` to get a list of parameters for that module:

`modinfo -p snd_hda_intel`

```
index:Index value for Intel HD audio interface. (array of int)
id:ID string for Intel HD audio interface. (array of charp)
enable:Enable Intel HD audio interface. (array of bool)
model:Use the given board model. (array of charp)
position_fix:DMA pointer read method.(-1 = system default, 0 = auto, 1 = LPIB, 2 = POSBUF, 3 = VIACOMBO, 4 = COMBO). (array of int)
bdl_pos_adj:BDL position adjustment offset. (array of int)
probe_mask:Bitmask to probe codecs (default = -1). (array of int)
probe_only:Only probing and no codec initialization. (array of int)
jackpoll_ms:Ms between polling for jack events (default = 0, using unsol events only) (array of int)
single_cmd:Use single command to communicate with codecs (for debugging only). (bool)
enable_msi:Enable Message Signaled Interrupt (MSI) (bint)
patch:Patch file for Intel HD audio interface. (array of charp)
beep_mode:Select HDA Beep registration mode (0=off, 1=on) (default=1). (array of bool)
power_save:Automatic power-saving timeout (in second, 0 = disable). (xint)
power_save_controller:Reset controller in power save mode. (bool)
align_buffer_size:Force buffer and period sizes to be multiple of 128   bytes. (bint)
snoop:Enable/disable snooping (bint)
```

The man pages for `modinfo` show using a `-F` flag with a field name to print a field value. I tried `modinfo -F id snd_hda_intel` but it produced no output.

`/proc/asound/` has folders for both cards (under `card0` and `card1`). These folders in turn had `id` files. A quick `cat /proc/asound/card0/id` resulted in `HDMI`, likewise for card1 it was `PCH`.

As a bit of a blind attempt, I added the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# fix ordering of HDMI and PCH soundcards on Chromebook
options snd_hda_intel index=0,1 id=PCH,HDMI
```

This answer was the originally the end of the question, but after a system restart, this change to `alsa-base.conf` had fixed the problem.